# [13.5.2]Create DataStore through ssoadm.jsp -> Atttribut dont match with 'service schema'

Tags: openam

I want to create a DataSore through ssoadm.jsp because I use endpoint url in order to automatize process of configuration.

`[localhost]/ssoadm.jsp?cmd=create-datastore`

I put:

```
domain name (previously created with default coniguration): myDomain
data store name: myDataStore
type of DataStore: LDAPv3
Attribut values: LDAPv3=org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo
```

Then I got something like: Attribute name "LDAPv3" doesn't match with service schema. What am I supposed to put in those fields "Attribut values" pls? An example is given:

`"sunIdRepoClass=com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.files.FilesRepo"`

PS: I dont want to create datastore from [Localhost]/realm/IDRepoSelectType because there is jato.pageSession that i can't automaticly get.

PS2: it is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow, sorry if my question didn't fit with the expectation. I tried my best.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssoadm.jsp?cmd=list-datastore-types
```

shows the list of user data store types
Every user data store type has specific attributes to be set. Unfortunately those are not explicitly documented. The service attributes are defined in the related service definition XML template, which is loaded (after potential tag swapping) into the OpenAM configuration data store during initial configuration. For the user data stores you can find them in `OPENAM_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY/template/xml/idRepoService.xml`

E.g. for user data store type `LDAPv3` the following service attributes are defined

```
sunIdRepoClass
sunIdRepoAttributeMapping
sunIdRepoSupportedOperations
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-ldapv3Generic
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-ldap-server
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-authid
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-authpw
openam-idrepo-ldapv3-heartbeat-interval
openam-idrepo-ldapv3-heartbeat-timeunit
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-organization_name
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-connection-mode
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-connection_pool_min_size
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-connection_pool_max_size
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-max-result
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-time-limit
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-search-scope
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-users-search-attribute
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-users-search-filter
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-user-objectclass
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-user-attributes
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-createuser-attr-mapping
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-isactive
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-active
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-inactive
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-groups-search-attribute
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-groups-search-filter
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-group-container-name
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-group-container-value
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-group-objectclass
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-group-attributes
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-memberof
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-uniquemember
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-memberurl
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-dftgroupmember
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-roles-search-attribute
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-roles-search-filter
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-role-search-scope
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-role-objectclass
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-filterrole-objectclass
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-filterrole-attributes
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-nsrole
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-nsroledn
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-nsrolefilter
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-people-container-name
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-people-container-value
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-auth-naming-attr
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-psearchbase
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-psearch-filter
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-psearch-scope
com.iplanet.am.ldap.connection.delay.between.retries
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-service-attributes
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-dncache-enabled
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-dncache-size
openam-idrepo-ldapv3-behera-support-enabled
```

It might be best that you create an user data store instance via console and then use `ssoadm.jsp?cmd=show-datastore` to list the properties. You would get a long list of attriutes ... to much to show here.
When you create the data store, make sure you specify the password for the bind DN using property

```
sun-idrepo-ldapv3-config-authpw=PASSWORD
```